# What is Artificial Nipple Dilation?

Tags: novel, philip-k-dick, clans-of-the-alphane-moon

[image: Artificially Dilated Nipples?]
<sub>(source: [netdna-ssl.com](https://bhb9jmzyvo39u57v3yqabot5d-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/alphane.jpg))</sub>

In Phillip K. Dick’s [Clans of the Alphane Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clans_of_the_Alphane_Moon), the procedure is named while introducing Mary:

> “Let off on the roof field Mary descended by in-ramp to floor ninety, came to the glass door, hesitated, then allowed it to open and entered the outer office in which Mr. Field’s receptionist — very pretty, with much make-up and a rather tight spider-silk sweater — sat. Mary felt annoyed at the girl; just because bras had become passe, did a girl with so pronounced a bosom have to cater to fashion? In this case practicality dictated a bra, and Mary stood at the desk feeling herself flushing with disapproval. **And artificial nipple dilation; it was just too much.**”

What was nipple dilation? Some new fashion trend? Some type of more permanent surgery? Was it ever explained?

Comment: The higher resolution picture of that cover is quite suggestive; https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1387735686l/883604.jpg

Comment: Congratulations for the most startling question I have seen in my RSS feed for months.

Comment: Risky click of the day

Comment: Safe to say that PK Dick just wanted an excuse to write about breasts.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's a fashion trend. It evidently requires some sort of surgical operation to make the nipples larger and more prominent.

> Joan Trieste wore skin-tight dark pants and slippers and a cotton
> man’s-style shirt; as far as he could tell, she had on no bra, as
> fashion dictated, but her nipples were merely flat dark circles
> beneath the white cotton fabric of her shirt: **she could not afford or
> did not care to have the currently-popular dilation operation. It came
> to him then that she was poor. Possibly a student.**

and

> “She has big breasts,” Chuck said.
>
> “Who? Patty? Oh yes.” Hentman nodded. “Well, it’s that operation they
> give in Hollywood and New York. **It’s more the rage now than the
> dilation, and she’s had that done, too.**

Comment: Given the reference to "_flat_ dark circles", it seems safe to assume it includes making the nipples erect.

Comment: @JackAidley - Hence "*more prominent*" (e.g. Adj. projecting from something; protuberant)

Answer (score 8):

I don't believe it's explained in the story, but given "[dilation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dilation)" generally refers to an expansion with an implication of making it more open, my guess is that, at the least, the receptionist has done something to make her nipples larger, with a possibility that this is done in a way to make them look more open (which kind of falls into the false thinking that nipples have a single opening for milk, while it's actually secreted from multiple ducts that the concavity of the tip tends to make appear to come out in a single stream).

Comment: "with a possibility that this is done in a way to make them look more open" My assumption would be piercings like ear stretchers, which sort of makes me wince.

Comment: @nick012000: My brain went more into implanted rings, but yeah... I almost added a comment that people who want a reference on what a "more open" appearance might look like could check into Japanese hentai, which occasionally includes openings large enough to *cough* interact with.